# Correct usage of in vs on

Tags: american-english

Which of the following statements is correct? And, what is the difference?

> What was decided in the call?
>
> What was decided on the call?

By call, I am referring to a conference (phone) call.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would not use either, but "What was decided during the call?"

Answer (score -1):

**on** would be the correct term. This is something most people would probably accept either way though. For using the phone, think of it like being "on the computer". When you use the computer - you're not "in" the computer when you use it.

"on" usually refers to placement on top of a surface, such as putting a cup on a table. "In" tends to refer to being "inside" something such as an object, a place, or inside a period of time (We're **in** the month of August right now!).

Comment: I don't think any native speaker would ever say that. Please take the site [tour]. Answers are expected to be well researched and backed up by evidence. Your answer might pass as a comment, but you don't have sufficient rep yet to post comments. Please stick around and wait to answer a question that you can support with reasearch and expertise.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree, I would be **on** the phone (or computer) but I would be **in** the conversation that was taking place. This would apply to a text, email or forum conversation too. In fact I am **on** my tablet taking part **in** a discussion of this question at this moment. The word **on** tends to be used to specify the technological hardware used for communication (radio, phone, television, computer) while **in** tends to be used for the ongoing communication itself. The word **by** is also used but refers to the actual medium ("by letter", "by email", "by phone")